# SQL update command not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-3.0, sqldataadapter

I have created a web page in Asp.net website. The following page load will run as it gets arguments from previous page. The page also has an option for editing the contents and updating in database. But when the button(save) is clicked it doesn't update the database.Kindly help in this. But when there is no connection in page load the update command works.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String cust=Request.QueryString["custName"];
    String env = Request.QueryString["env"];
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cnn.ConnectionString = connStr;
    cnn.Open();
    view();
    if (env == "Production")
    {
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Customer_Production where Customer_Name=@cust", cnn);
        SqlCommandBuilder m_cbCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        cnn.Close();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer_Production where Customer_Name=@cust", cnn);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust", cust);
        adapter.Fill(MyDataSet, "Servers");
        foreach (DataRow myRow in MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            custName.Value = myRow["Customer_name"].ToString();
            custMaintain.Value= myRow["Customer_Maintenance"].ToString();
            serviceAffect.Value=myRow["Systems/Services_Affected"].ToString();
            email_Content.Value= myRow["Email_Content"].ToString();
            email_Signature.Value= myRow["Email_Signature"].ToString();
            email_From.Value=myRow["Email_From"].ToString();
            email_To.Value=myRow["Email_To"].ToString();
            email_Cc.Value=myRow["Email_Cc"].ToString();
            email_Bcc.Value=myRow["Email_Bcc"].ToString();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Customer_Non_Production where Customer_Name=@cust", cnn);
        SqlCommandBuilder m_cbCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        cnn.Close();
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer_Production where Customer_Name=@cust", cnn);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust", cust);
        adapter.Fill(MyDataSet, "Servers");


        foreach (DataRow myRow in MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            custName.Value = myRow["Customer_name"].ToString();
            custMaintain.Value = myRow["Customer_Maintenance"].ToString();
            serviceAffect.Value = myRow["Systems/Services_Affected"].ToString();

            email_Content.Value = myRow["Email_Content"].ToString();
            email_Signature.Value = myRow["Email_Signature"].ToString();
            email_From.Value = myRow["Email_From"].ToString();
            email_To.Value = myRow["Email_To"].ToString();
            email_Cc.Value = myRow["Email_Cc"].ToString();
            email_Bcc.Value = myRow["Email_Bcc"].ToString();

        }
    }
```

The following is the button click for Save Button(for update command)

```
 protected void save_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Button Click Save
    /*        String id = "A";
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cnn.ConnectionString = connStr;
    cnn.Open();
    String sql = String.Format("Update Customer_Production set Email_Signature='{0}' where Customer_Name like '{1}'",TextBox1.Text,id);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     */
    String cust = "A";
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cnn.ConnectionString = connStr;
    cnn.Open();
    if (env.Value == "Production")
    {
        //String sql = String.Format("Update Customer_Production set Customer_Maintenance='{0}',Environment='{1}',[Systems/Services_Affected]='{2}',Email_Content='{3}',Email_Signature='{4}',Email_To='{5}',Email_Cc='{6}',Email_Bcc='{7}',Email_From='{8}' where Customer_Name like '{9}' ", "custMaintain.Value","env.Value","serviceAffect.Value","email_Content.Value","email_To.Value","email_Cc.Value","email_Bcc.Value","email_From.Value", "cust");
        String sql = String.Format("Update Customer_Production set Email_Signature='{0}' where Customer_Name like '{1}'", email_Signature.Value,cust);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: not to be captn obvious here but maybe `env.Value != "Production"`

Comment: @Hogan I need Production thats why i have checked that..

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @ChetanGoenka - I know why your code is like that -- even if it is a bad design.  (You should use a different DB for production and then just change the connection string--using the same code in both places).  My point was different.  Are you sure the variable `env.Value` is assigned the value "`Production`" in your code?  *IF 
NOT* that would explain your problem.

Comment: @Trifon then can you please tell me better way for updating ?

Comment: @Hogan yes it has env.Value as "Production"

Comment: How are you checking whether the data was updated? What is your connection string? (If it has `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName`, STOP DOING THAT.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand while updating again in page_load function it will show results.

Comment: @ChetanGoenka see this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ChetanGoenka Did you get your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why having a connection (or not) in the `Page_Load` would make a difference, but here's one thing that looks off to me:

```
String.Format(
   "Update Customer_Production set Email_Signature='{0}' where Customer_Name like '{1}'",        
   email_Signature.Value,
   cust);
```

(I broke it into several lines because the part I'm interested in is the last part of the format string.)

You've set `cust` to "A" earlier in that method.  So the SQL that will result will look (at the end) like this:

```
 ... where Customer_Name like 'A'
```

Unless you have a customer name that is exactly equal to A, that's not going to return anything, and therefore no records will be updated.  You're forgetting the '%' wildcard.

I agree with all those who have pointed out that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection (and you'll also have a problem with single quotes), but just to show you what it needs to look like, here it is with the wildcard:

```
 Update Customer_Production set Email_Signature='{0}' where Customer_Name like '{1}%'
```

Comment: I have one customer name with A. I wanted to test it so I gave  it A. But with that itself its not working.